# Reusing address and port in PHP websockets

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I'm implementing websockets for a chat system. The server.php is being invoked via ssh with `php /www/server.php`, and the first time it executes fine; but if the process is stopped (ctrl+z), this error is displayed after trying to invoke `php /www/server.php` again:

```
Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [48]: Address already in use in /www/server.php
```

These are the contents of the **/www/server.php** file:

```
<?
$host = '10.10.0.103';
$port = '1337';

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

// ... etc
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Can I reuse the same address / port after stopping the `php /www/server.php` job with a FLAG? Isn't **SO_REUSEADDR** supposed to reuse the same address/port?
2. What are the best practices for this issue? Restarting the websockets server could be an everyday task, e.g.: after updating the contents of **/www/server.php**

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: `stopped` as in suspended, e.g. you ctrl-z the php process? that doesn't shut down the process, and any bindings you established in it will still be alive.

Comment: Exactly, ctrl-z. But if I suspend the process, the client can't connect anymore to the websocket server, that's why i supposed it was stopped.

Comment: yes, because the process that should be handling the rest of the connection negotation has been stopped, so no connections can be made. But that doesn't mean the socket's been release. it's still in use. it's like "hey, this frozen caveman isn't speaking to me". well, yeah... he's frozen.

Comment: I understand. Then I would need to better understand question number 2: how can I run the process (while allowing me to close the terminal window), and how could I really STOP the process (or RESTART it) after making changes to server.php?

Comment: kill it. e.g. `kill -9 pid_of_php_process`, or ctrl-c the script and start it again `./php server_script.php`. Suspending with ctrl-z doesn't kill the job, it just freezes it so no more code execution occurs. but suspending doesn't release any resources the process was using. files stay open, sockets stay bound, memory is consumed, etc...

Comment: So I can just restart it, it needs to be killed and the called again. Just did that, it worked fine. So, how can I run the websockets server and still have control of the terminal for other things?

Comment: run it in the background. `php server_script.php &`, or run it inside a `screen` session.